# PHP Transform Array parent-tree relationship into Object parent-tree relationship

Tags: php

My question is:

How do I transform the PHP array code below to a more flexible, lean and mean object-oriented code?

I have tried numerous things including with PHP's SPL. Unfortunately we are still working with PHP 5.2.3 which means that several handy SPL functions do not exist yet. 
Upgrading to PHP 5.3.x. is not an option.

```
// $data array that comes from a SQL result
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parentID] => 115
            [childID] => 1718
            [some_attr] => 146
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parentID] => 121
            [childID] => 1301
            [some_attr] => 105
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [parentID] => 121
            [childID] => 1300
            [some_attr] => 2
        )
)
```

With the following code I created an array like this:

```
// $children array
Array
(
    [115] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [childID] => 1718
                        [some_attr] => 146
                    )

            )

    [121] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [childID] => 1301
                        [some_attr] => 105
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [childID] => 1300
                        [some_attr] => 2
                    )
            )
)
```

The code to create the parent-tree array above:

```
// $data array is populated from a SQL query

$children = array();

foreach ($data as $key=>$row) {
    $parent = (int)$row['parentID'];
    if( !isset($children[$parent]) ) {
        $children[$parent] = array();
    }
    // Remove parent id, because we already have it as a key in the array
    unset($row['parentID']);       
    $children[$parent][$key] = $row;
}
```

---

This is what I came up with so far.

```
// ParentContainer
class ParentObject  {
    public $parentID;
    public $children = array();
}

// The actual tree: parent-child relationships
// parent
// |
// |___ child 1
// |___ child 2


class Tree_alpha {

    /**
     * @var int $parent  //parent is the key for this node
     */
    public $parent;

    public $parentObject;

    /* Child Nodes */
    protected $children = array();

    // Data for the node
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($parent = null, $data = null) {
        $this->parent = $parent;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->parentObject = new ParentObject();
    }

    public function addChild($parent, $key, $data = null)  {
        if (!$this->parentObject = $this->findParent($parent) ) {
          $this->children = array();
        }
        unset($data['parentID']);
        $this->parentObject->parentID = $parent;
        $this->parentObject->children[$parent][$key] = $data;
    }

    public function findParent($parent) {
      if ($this->parentObject->parentID == $parent) {
        return $this->parentObject;
      } else {
        return new ParentObject();
      }

      //return isset($children[$parent]);
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Into which concrete problem did you run with your code? And how did you finally solve it?